# Whether I should use “without” or to use “except” in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

I have read a sentence in “New Concept English”, that is, *Harrison had thought of everything except the weather*. Here is the context:

> Harrison lived in Mediterranean for many years before returning to England. He had no sooner settled down than he started to complain about the weather in England because it is always sunny in the place where he lived before. Harrison had thought of everything except the weather.

My question is that if I can use *without* in the last sentence. In other words, do you think it is acceptable to say *Harrison had thought of everything without the weather?*  I’m looking forward to know the reasons in detail. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Except** is used when some member/s of a set, stated or implied, are excluded for some reason:

> all the whole numbers except multiples of 10
>
> all the class except Ann
>
> all birds except penguins
>
> all factors that would affect him ('everything') except the weather.

**Without** (in the fairly closely related sense) means unaccompanied by / not possessing (usually something one might guess might possibly be present):

> all the class (members) without packed lunches
>
> all birds without flippers.

So 'except' (or but or bar) is appropriate here, not 'without' (which is often replaceable by 'lacking').

Comment: I deeply appreciate your timely help. The explaination really makes sense.